# Modifying a chip on a bought voltage measurer

Tags: batteries, integrated-circuit, voltage-measurement, hacking

I have bought a battery checker for my RC LiPo battery packs. The battery checker can measure and alarm at low voltages between 2.7 and 3.8 volts, however with LiPo batteries, the interesting range is between 3.7 and 3.8 volts and I was wondering if it was possible to accommodate this range instead?

In the circuitry there is an Atmel 1206 24C02N chip. I found [the datasheet for the chip here](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc0180.pdf) and it seems like the chip is the one that holds the voltage levels in it's memory (am I right?). I was wondering if it was possible to read and alter the chips memory through Arduino or something similar. I have an [FTDI connector like this one](https://www.google.dk/search?q=ftdi%20connector&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=WTy1U66ZCqH_ygOXpYGgCw&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1366&bih=667#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=QEkDDS0wZzUIQM%253A%3Bl4SSHV0SHh9HlM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fnicegear.co.nz%252Fobj%252Fimages%252F09716-_00.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fnicegear.co.nz%252Felectronics-gear%252Fsparkfun-ftdi-breakout-5v%252F%3B600%3B600) that I normally connect with my Arduino nano. Can I use this one to communicate with the chip?

Here is an image of the back of the voltage checker. On the front there are two buzzers, a 3 segment LED display and in the top you can see the button that changes the voltage level at which the alarm should trigger.

[image: enter image here]

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to write to the 24C02, which is just an I2C SEEPROM memory. Anything that will act as an I2C master will work.

Working out *what* to change in the 256 bytes of memory will be a more difficult problem I suspect, and very specific to this particular end product. It may be stored in a very naive way, or (like some stuff I've developed) there may be redundancy and self-repair algorithms involved, along with the checksums or CRCs to detect problems.